# C# dataGridView reentrance error

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

My program loads data from a MySQL database into a `DataGridView`. I want to hide the first column (`id` column), but I get the reentrance cell error.

CODE:

```
void dataGridGlavni_CellFormatting(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dataGridGlavni.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "id")
        {
            this.dataGridGlavni.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Visible = false; // <<<< error
        }
        if (this.dataGridGlavni.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Plate za mesec")
        {
            GlavniForm.ShortFormDateFormat(e);
        }
    }
```

ERROR:

> Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.

The error also appears when I use the following line:

```
this.dataGridGlavni.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

However it does NOT appear when I use these lines:

```
this.dataGridGlavni.Columns[1].Visible = false;
```

OR

```
this.dataGridGlavni.Columns["Plate za mesec"].Visible = false;
```

I googled a lot and haven't been able to find the source of the error. What is happening why  won't it let me hide the first column ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error did not show once I set the AutoSizeColumnsMode and AutoSizeRowsMode.

Answer (score 0):

you should first checkout the position of your id reflect in my sql and then after you can use

dataGridGlavni.Columns[0].Visible = false;

or whatever its position.

Comment: It is in the first position.